# has_many and belongs (+ polymorphic)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Company, which is on top of the hierarchy. All questions asked by a user, belongs to the company. Currently a question has many to many relationship with groups and users. Which means that a question can be assigned to a group(s) or user(s).

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :answers
  has_many :question_participants
  has_many :users, through: :question_participants,
                   source: :questionable, source_type: 'User'
  has_many :groups, through: :question_participants,
                    source: :questionable, source_type: 'Group'
```

the association is done through a polymorphic, which is question_participants. Now what I wish to accomplish is to allow a question to belong to a company (which it currently does) but also be assigned to that company.

I've tried just adding it like this:

```
  has_many :companies, through: :question_participants,
                    source: :questionable, source_type: 'Company'
```

and on the company model do:

```
  has_many :questions
  has_many :question_participants, as: :questionable
  has_many :questions, through: :question_participants
```

now the issue is that a question will that has many and belong to, which I think is the right approach but I'm not sure how to set this all up correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by 'assigned to a company'? What's the difference between 'belonging' to it.

Comment: by assigned I mean that the question is targeted to that. Whilst belong is the creator of the question (the company) now what I'd like is for the company to be the creator, but also to be the one the question is targeted at.

Comment: Can a question target several companies at once? Or is a question always targeted at a single company? Finally, can a question NOT be targeted at any company?